# Почему холод "собачий"?

Tags: фразеология

И имеет ли это выражение отношение к "замерз как собака", "в такую погоду хороший хозяин собаку не выпустит" ?

Comment: Когда-то разбирались с этой идиомой (фразеологизмом?), но ничего умнее "холода, при котором мерзнут даже собаки" не придумали. Хотя что-то мне подсказывает, что тут возможна более глубокая идея.

Comment: С собакой вообще почему-то связываются различные негативные ассоциации (зол, как собака). Даже то, что "собака" - ругательство.  Помните определение: "Интеллигентный человек - это тот, кто называет кошку кошкой, даже если споткнулся об нее и упал".   
Если задуматься, это странно, ведь собака - друг человека. (Хотя, конечно, не всякого, а только хозяина).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наиболее логичной выглядит версия, что холод такой, что дабы собаки не околели, их приходится держать дома. Во время сильных морозов крестьяне довольно часто приводили в отапливаемую избу коров и лошадей, а если ещё и собаку пришлось в дом пустить, то морозы действительно зверские.

Comment: В целом версия та же, что м та, о которой я упоминал.
В частности - не могу вспомнить, чтобы дворовых собак дальше сеней пускали. А вот в сени пускали не только в мороз, скорее уж в грозу или бюрю...

Answer (score 1):

В английском языке есть похожее выражение "Three dogs night", предположительно возникшее во времена заселения Америки. Наиболее распространённая версия об истоках такова: поселенцы северной части континента, переживая суровые зимы на новом месте, иногда пускали в кровать собак, чтобы те их согревали. Соответственно, в холодные ночи пускали одну собаку, в более холодные - пару, а в "собачий холод" / "three dogs night" забывали об удобстве (собаки не склонны спать компактно и зачастую могут спихнуть с кровати самого хозяина) и пускали аж троих. Возможно, в русском языке источник тот же.

Answer (score 0):

В голландском есть выражение *собачья погода - honden weer*. Оно значит, что в такую погоду разве что с собакой выйдешь погулять.